# How to use extundelete on AZURE VM?

Tags: azure, mongodb

I have an instance of MongoDB running on an AZURE VM, which gets all data dropped. I was trying to find if some file is still there, by using the below command:

```
$ sudo extundelete --restore-all /dev/sda1
extundelete: Bad magic number in super-block when trying to open filesystem /dev/sda1
```

However, it is returning error. I also tried debugfs, which returns the same error.

The disks of my server are listed below:

```
$ sudo fdisk -lu    
Disk /dev/sda: 32.2 GB, 32212254720 bytes, 62914560 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00069ce8

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    62914559    31456256   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 7516 MB, 7516192768 bytes, 14680064 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x45acb57d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1             128    14678015     7338944   83  Linux
```

Anyone can help me?